# Sub parameter declared as Application type variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have this subroutine to turn on/off some of `Application`'s properties.

```
Public Sub OPTIMIZE_VBA(ByVal isOn As Boolean)
Dim bHolder As Boolean
bHolder = Not isOn
On Error Resume Next
With Application
  .DisplayAlerts = bHolder
  .ScreenUpdating = bHolder
  .EnableEvents = bHolder
  .Calculation = IIf(isOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
  .Calculate
    If .VERSION > 12 Then .PrintCommunication = bHolder
End With
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Say that there is a different instance of application that I wish to turn on/off the same properties,how would I be able to modify this code to accept an argument/parameter as a different application?
I'm expecting something like;

```
Public Sub OPTIMIZE_VBA(ByVal isOn As Boolean, Optional ByVal ExApp As Excel.Application = thisApplication)
' rest of the code
End Sub
```

With this I can call it like;

```
Sub Create_New_Excel_and_Disable_Properties()
'<~ Declare and prepare the new application
  Dim NewExcel As Excel.Application
  Set NewExcel = New Excel.Application

'<~ declare and set the workbook variable
Dim ExcelWbk As Excel.Workbook
Set ExcelWbk = NewExcel.Workbooks.Open("folder\template.xlsx")

'<~ call the sub that disables the Application.properties
OPTIMIZE_VBA False, NewExcel
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Sub OPTIMIZE_VBA(ByVal isOn As Boolean, Optional ByVal ExApp As Excel.Application)

If IsEmpty(ExApp) Or ExApp Is Nothing Then
    Set ExApp = Application
End If

' rest of the code
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess you have to use `set`

Comment: Can I assume that I won't be able to set the exapp to Application?

Comment: @RomcelGeluz Correct, only constant expressions can be assigned to `Optional` parameters

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
Public Sub OPTIMIZE_VBA(ByVal isOn As Boolean, Optional ByVal ExApp As Excel.Application = Nothing)

    If ExApp Is Nothing Then Set ExApp = Application
    ' rest of the code

End Sub
```

Comment: Both of your comments are well appreciated.